# Python: Add Button via Tkinter

Tags: python, button, canvas, tkinter

I am trying to add a third button to two already existing ones. But always get an error message and don't know what is wrong.

```
Import Tkinter as tki

btn = tki.Button(self.root, text="yes!", command=self.yes, fg="black", bg="white", font=("Courier", 22))
btn.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="NSEW" )
btn2 = tki.Button(self.root, text="No!", command=self.no, fg="black", bg="white", font=("Courier", 22))
btn2.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="NSEW")
btn3 = tki.Button(self.root, text="HELP", command=self.help, fg="black", bg="white", font=("Courier",22))
btn3.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="NSEW" )

self.w = tki.Canvas(self.root,width=48,height=48, bg="white")
self.w.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=3)
self.circle = self.w.create_oval(2,2,48,48,fill="white")
```

no, yes and help are implemented in the code. and for no and yes everything works. but now I always get an IndentationError: unexpected indent.
Can you please help me?

Comment: the code you shared is not complete. `self. w` and `self. circle` should be in a class

Comment: what is an indentation error?

Comment: I know that the code is not complete, it is just to Show you what the Problem is.

Comment: the issue is in the code you haven't shared.

Comment: Can you provide (at least) the complete error message? We cannot diagnose an error if we don't know what the error is and what is causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your specific Button Code. Indentation Error occur, when your formatting is wrong. your lines always start with a specified number of blanks or tabs (called Indentation). somewhere this went wrong.

To get rid of this, check all your Indents in the beginning of your lines. And very important do not mixup tabs and blanks

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Judith if it was the right solution for your answer please click the check on the left to approve the answer